# How Python unpack http response data

Tags: python

there
I use python to pull data from Oanda API, and get data in the format like below:, I don't know how to unpack it, so I can get a time series, is there someone who can help me? thank you!

```
{
    "instrument" : "EUR_USD",
    "granularity" : "M15",
    "candles" : [
        {
            "time" : "2015-10-01T19:15:00.000000Z",
            "openBid" : 1.11833,
            "openAsk" : 1.11846,
            "highBid" : 1.1186,
            "highAsk" : 1.11874,
            "lowBid" : 1.11825,
            "lowAsk" : 1.1184,
            "closeBid" : 1.1184,
            "closeAsk" : 1.11857,
            "volume" : 205,
            "complete" : true
        },
        {
            "time" : "2015-10-01T19:30:00.000000Z",
            "openBid" : 1.11844,
            "openAsk" : 1.1186,
            "highBid" : 1.11924,
            "highAsk" : 1.1194,
            "lowBid" : 1.11839,
            "lowAsk" : 1.11857,
            "closeBid" : 1.11908,
            "closeAsk" : 1.11926,
            "volume" : 290,
            "complete" : true
        },
        {
            "time" : "2015-10-01T19:45:00.000000Z",
            "openBid" : 1.11906,
            "openAsk" : 1.11922,
            "highBid" : 1.11933,
            "highAsk" : 1.1195,
            "lowBid" : 1.11868,
            "lowAsk" : 1.11883,
            "closeBid" : 1.11868,
            "closeAsk" : 1.11883,
            "volume" : 206,
            "complete" : true
        },
        {
            "time" : "2015-10-01T20:00:00.000000Z",
            "openBid" : 1.11865,
            "openAsk" : 1.11879,
            "highBid" : 1.11884,
            "highAsk" : 1.119,
            "lowBid" : 1.11827,
            "lowAsk" : 1.11844,
            "closeBid" : 1.11833,
            "closeAsk" : 1.11848,
            "volume" : 114,
            "complete" : true
        }]
}
```

Comment: That is just JSON. Python has a built-in json library.

Comment: I am new to python, thank your for your tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the standard json module (see [here](https://pymotw.com/2/json/) for a good explanation on how to encode and decode)

```
import json
s = '''
    your json sample
    '''
d = json.loads(s)
```

then you can access the elements of the structure within the `d` dictionary

e.g.

```
d['instrument']
```

or

```
d['candles'][0]['lowBid']
```

Comment: you r right, thank you for saving my ass

Comment: I have to say you r a genius, know exactly what my question was. problem addressed, thank you

Comment: please master rub the accept/upvote button then :D

Comment: I promise you I have clicked the up-vote button more than 10 times, but it does not work, it says I have to earn more than 15 reputation first, then my vote will change the publicly displayed displayed post score. :(

Comment: and what about accepting the answer? does it work? BTW the other answer you got is just as good as mine

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module

```
from json import loads

mydata = """{
    "instrument": "EUR_USD",
    "granularity": "M15",
    "candles": [
        {
            "time": "2015-10-01T19:15:00.000000Z",
            "openBid": 1.11833,
            "openAsk": 1.11846,
            "highBid": 1.1186,
            "highAsk": 1.11874,
            "lowBid": 1.11825,
            "lowAsk": 1.1184,
            "closeBid": 1.1184,
            "closeAsk": 1.11857,
            "volume": 205,
            "complete": true
        }
    ]
}"""

jdata = json.loads(mydata)
jdata['instrument']
>>> u'EUR_USD
```

Comment: you r right, thank you for saving my ass